# Why couldn't Vegeta keep his body?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In Dragon Ball Z before Vegeta sacrifices himself in the fight with Majin Buu, Vegeta asks Picolo if he is going to see Goku when he dies.

Picolo answers him that only great warriors who did great great deeds are able to keep their bodies, and that Vegeta had had a life of selfish and only though of himself.
And so far so good, as in other ocasions, for example when Goku died for the first time, kami told Goku the same thing.

But looking at other characters (Raditz, Ginyu Special Forces, Frieza, Cell, Dabura, ...) they were able to keep their bodies after death, and we all know they were evil.

One would assume that if the characters above were given the body after dead, Vegeta should be able to keep his, right? And to add to that, Vegeta sacrificed himself trying to save the planet earth and his family.

Comment: I know there is already a DBZ tag here but should questions like these be migrated to Anime.SE going forward?

Comment: @kaine It's on topic here. It's just that there may be more knowledgeable members over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the manga we actually never see any evidence of the villains mentioned in your post having any body. We also never meet pikkon, generally the time spent by goku in the other world is not documented much in the manga.

However in the anime and also the newest movie Ressurection F we see Frieza has apparently been given a body in hell in order to suffer more in the afterlife. I think that there is overwhelming evidence that in the Anime the villains are given bodies. This is mainly the case to have the story arcs like in "Warriors of the Dead".

As a note, Vegeta did infact keep his body. King Yemma kept his body just in case he could help with Majin Buu. He never actually spends time as a spirit in the other world and during the remainder of the Buu Saga he learns the err of his ways and is then revived.

Also as another note, King Yemma is weaker than King Kai who is weaker than both Vegeta and Nappa when they first come to earth. This makes it impossible for King Yemma to be able to subdue villains with bodies, but we clearly see Cell unable to fight back when he is being judge.

**TL:DR It's an Anime only plot-hole needed for filler story arcs**